# How do I crop an image on a white background with python?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am scanning old photos, so I have the image and a white background from the scanner. My aim is to take the picture, removing the white background. How can I do that ?

An example picture is the following:
[image]

My simple approach:

```
import os
import time
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

def get_cropped_image(image, crop_folder, threshold):
    image_name = image.split("\\")[-1]
    im = Image.open(image)
    pixels = im.load()
    width, height = im.size

    rows = []
    for h_index in xrange(height):
        row = []
        for w_index in xrange(width):
            row.append(pixels[((w_index, h_index))])
        color_count = Counter(row)[(255, 255, 255)] / float(len(row))
        rows.append([h_index, color_count])

    columns = []
    for w_index in xrange(width):
        column = []
        for h_index in xrange(height):
            column.append(im.getpixel((w_index, h_index)))
        color_count = Counter(column)[(255, 255, 255)] / float(len(column))
        columns.append([w_index, color_count])

    image_data = csv.writer(open("image_data.csv", "wb")).writerows(zip(rows, columns))

    rows_indexes = [i[0] for i in rows if i[1] < threshold]
    columns_indexes = [i[0] for i in columns if i[1] < threshold]

    x1, y1, x2, y2 = columns_indexes[0], rows_indexes[0], columns_indexes[-1], rows_indexes[-1]

    im.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2)).save(os.path.join(cropped_folder, "c_" + image_name))
```

Comment: Checkout blob detection algorithms and methods. SimpleCV library has some. Checkout : http://simplecv.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/cookbook/

Comment: Do you have an example picture that we can see?

Comment: They are personal photographs so I can't show one. Imagine putting a printed photograph on the scanner and scan it. It creates an image with the printed photograph and a white background.

Comment: I have added an example image and my code so far.

Answer (score 6):

In the example below, I create a mask by selecting all pixels that are close to white (close, because the values right outside the area of interest are not exactly white).  I then invert the mask to find pixels potentially belonging to the image.  I then calculate the bounding box of those pixels, and use it to extract the region of interest.

```
from skimage import io, img_as_float
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


image = img_as_float(io.imread('universe.jpg'))

# Select all pixels almost equal to white
# (almost, because there are some edge effects in jpegs
# so the boundaries may not be exactly white)
white = np.array([1, 1, 1])
mask = np.abs(image - white).sum(axis=2) < 0.05

# Find the bounding box of those pixels
coords = np.array(np.nonzero(~mask))
top_left = np.min(coords, axis=1)
bottom_right = np.max(coords, axis=1)

out = image[top_left[0]:bottom_right[0],
            top_left[1]:bottom_right[1]]

plt.imshow(out)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It works perfectly. It would be too complex to apply something like this to crop multiple images ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to crop multiple rectangular images out of a white background?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I have found a plugin for GIMP called divide scan images and a script called multicrop for imagemagick which I don't know how to use in windows.

Comment: Perhaps this software we wrote for the NHM (BSD license) will work for you: http://naturalhistorymuseum.github.io/inselect/

Comment: I've got 
`mask = np.abs(image - white).sum(axis=2) < 0.05
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1754,1240,4) (3,) `

Comment: It looks like the image you read in has an alpha channel.  After reading in the image, try `image = image[..., :3]` to drop the alpha channel.