# How do I crop all TIFF images on a white background in a folder with python3?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm scanning a book and now I'm on the final step. I need to crop all squared images with content in the center by white background without saving ratio. Some libs do not support TIFF format.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I combined some examples from [How do I crop an image on a white background with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310873/how-do-i-crop-an-image-on-a-white-background-with-python), [How do I crop an image on a white background with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310873/how-do-i-crop-an-image-on-a-white-background-with-python) and other questions. It works

```py
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io, img_as_float
import sys
import numpy as np
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filePaths = glob.glob("*.tif")

for filePath in filePaths:
    image = img_as_float(io.imread(filePath))
   
    white = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
    mask = np.abs(image - white).sum(axis=2) < 0.05

    coords = np.array(np.nonzero(~mask))
    top_left = np.min(coords, axis=1)
    bottom_right = np.max(coords, axis=1)

    out = image[top_left[0]:bottom_right[0],
                top_left[1]:bottom_right[1]]

    plt.imshow(out)
    # plt.show()
    
    fig = plt.gcf()
    for ax in fig.axes:
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.margins(0,0)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    fig.savefig(filePath + ".png", dpi=1200, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0)
```